# Unity3d attach texture to the cube problems

Tags: c#, 2d, textures

I have created a cube in the scene and I want to attach the texture to the cube by scripting.
The problem is there is no error of my code but The cube doesn't change after I press run in my program...

Here is my code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class testing : MonoBehaviour {


void start(){

    Texture2D tex = (Texture2D)Resources.Load("BlueColorTex.png", typeof(Texture2D));
    renderer.material.mainTexture = tex;

}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void start()
{
    Texture2D tex = (Texture2D)Resources.Load("BlueColorTex", typeof(Texture2D));
    renderer.material.mainTexture = tex;
}
```

Resources.Load does not use extensions. This is a common mistake.

> Returns the asset at path if it can be found otherwise returns null.
>   Only objects of type T will be returned. The path is relative to any
>   Resources folder inside the Assets folder of your project,
>   **extensions must be omitted.**

from: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html

Comment: But when I try to modify to  Texture2D tex = (Texture2D)Resources.Load("BlueColorTex", typeof(Texture2D));
it still not working...

Comment: Start debugging. Are you sure that BlueColorTex.png is in your resources folder? Is Tex valid before you assign it?

Comment: ya. I ensure that the png is in resource folder
Here is the pic http://answers.unity3d.com/storage/temp/44273-screen-shot-2015-04-10-at-44648-am.png